# How to UPDATE a table with NESTED JOIN. I am getting syntax error in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update

I am trying to UPDATE a table in MS Access but the table I cannot figure out what my Syntax Error is! MS Access throws "Syntax Error in Join expression" and highlights my SET command. Can anyone help spot my mistake?

```
UPDATE tbl_Items
INNER JOIN 

(SELECT *
FROM tbl_Inventory
INNER JOIN tbl_Inputs
ON tbl_Inventory.class = tbl_Inputs.class)

ON tbl_Items.PRODUCT_ID = tbl_Inputs.PRODUCT_ID

SET tbl_Items.status = tbl_Inventory.status

WHERE tbl_Items.status <> tbl_Inventory.status
```

As you can see, I want to update tbl_Items to have a status matching its corresponding record in tbl_Inventory. The query should only be applied to rows were tbl_Items and tbl_Inventory disagree. Before I can access tbl_Inventory, I need to join with tbl_Inputs.

Comment: Create a new SELECT? Do you mean my entire query recreated in design view? I dont understand how it fixes the join problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, which was to use AS to create a nickname.
The below query works:

```
UPDATE tbl_Items
INNER JOIN 

(SELECT *
FROM tbl_Inventory
INNER JOIN tbl_Inputs
ON tbl_Inventory.class = tbl_Inputs.class) AS nickname

ON tbl_Items.PRODUCT_ID = nickname.PRODUCT_ID

SET tbl_Items.status = nickname.status

WHERE tbl_Items.status <> nickname.status
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of Access syntax for this. However, in standard SQL, your statement should be written thus:

```
UPDATE  tbl_items
SET     tbl_items.status = tbl_Inventory.status
FROM    tbl_items
INNER JOIN tbl_Inputs
        ON tbl_items.PRODUCT_ID = tbl_Inputs.PRODUCT_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Inventory
        ON tbl_Inventory.class = tbl_Inputs.class
WHERE   tbl_items.status <> tbl_Inventory.status;
```

Furthermore, the `tbl_` prefix is unnecessary and bad practice. If @Celko were here he'd undoubtedly insist you remove it.